# Text overflow out of a panel in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The text inside the div panel is overflowing out of its boundary unpredictably. I can't seem to find the problem. Can anyone tell me why is it happening or how can I permanently solve this?
Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDqr9.png)!

Comment: I've found that this is unlikely if the text is directly inside the panel in e.g. a div. If you're putting a `.container` in a `.row` in a `.panel-body`, the CSS inherits other properties and stops wrapping text.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the following CSS property.

> The [**`word-wrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) CSS property is used to specify whether or not the
>   browser may break lines within words in order to prevent overflow when
>   an otherwise unbreakable string is too long to fit in its containing
>   box.

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

**`break-word`** Indicates that normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 uses of `word-break`, 1 In CSS:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

And other one in PHP, which will be useful for you/others in the future:

```
wordwrap($text, 100, "<br />", true); //Place your text in variable $text.
```